# MySQL only run a select statement if a condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can the following be done? Can't get it to work for me

```
SELECT * FROM DB_1593 WHERE DB_1593_field_0_3 = '--skills--' IF('--dateTime--' < NOW())
```

Comment: The decision whether or not to run a query is usually handled in your application layer (e.g. PHP, Java, C#).  Are you using MySQL with a programming language?

Comment: What is `--dateTime--` ?

Comment: I'm using a CRM which allows us to make basic sql queries, but i only want this to return a result if the condition is met, --dateTime-- is '2019-09-05 14:00:00' in this case

Comment: I am baffled by your attempted use of an if function as an extension to the where clause. In sql (of any dialect) the where clause determines the rows to be selected.

Comment: I though the question was clear enough, SQL isn't my strongest area, I was hoping for quick fix really without putting much effort in to be honest. Thanks anyway

Comment: @AndrewDaly Please have a look at my solution and let me know it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    DB_1593 
WHERE   DB_1593_field_0_3 = '--skills--' 
AND     '--dateTime--' < NOW()
```

Or even this works:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    DB_1593 
WHERE   DB_1593_field_0_3 = '--skills--' 
AND     IF('--dateTime--' < NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM DB_1593 
WHERE DB_1593_field_0_3 = '--skills--' AND IF('--dateTime--' < NOW())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your answer to include some explanation about the code you've included, and what you've changed from the question's query. This will improve the quality of your answer and make it easier for others to find you answer and upvote it :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the IF clause as

```
DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME = 2

IF (@COLUMN_NAME <= 3)
    Select * FROM DB_1593 WHERE DB_1593_field_0_3 = '--skills--'
```

Reference https://www.guru99.com/sql-server-if-else.html

Comment: Not like this in mysql